# How would you go about making this loop?

Tags: python, loops

A standard science experiment is to drop a ball and see how high it bounces. Once the “bounciness” of the ball has been determined, the ratio gives a bounciness index. For example, if a ball dropped from a height of 10 meters bounces 6 meters high, the index is 0.6 and the total distance traveled by the ball is 16 meters after one bounce. If the ball were to continue bouncing, the distance after two bounces would be 10 meters + 6 meters + 6 meters + 3.6 meters = 25.6 meters. Note that distance traveled for each successive bounce is the distance to the floor plus 0.6 of that distance as the ball comes back up.

Write a program that lets the user enter the initial height of the ball and the number of times the ball is allowed to continue bouncing. Output should be the total distance traveled by the ball.

What I have so far is :

```
def Bounce_Calculator():

    initialHeight = float(input( "What is the initial height? "))
    bouncesAllowed = float(input( "What is the amount of bounces allowed: "))
    bounceIndex = float(input("What is the bounce index : "))
    
    n=0
    while n <= bouncesAllowed :

        newHeight = float(initialHeight*bounceIndex)

        heightDifference = initialHeight-newHeight

        bounceSum = (newHeight/1-bounceIndex)
        totalDistance = ((((2*bounceSum) + initialHeight )))

        print ("The total distance is : ", totalDistance)

        n=bouncesAllowed + 1

Bounce_Calculator()
```

Comment: How do you expect the condition `n <= bouncesAllowed` to still be true after you assign `n=bouncesAllowed + 1` in your loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822). Copying and pasting the assignment specification is not a question; simply asking "how can I write this code" needs more focus. Showing us your existing code is only helpful if you ask a *specfic* question *about that code*. Please also read [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592.

Comment: You are continually multiplying the initial height by the bounce index. Shouldn't you be multiplying the *previous* height by the index? Also `newHeight/1-bounceIndex` looks like it is missing parentheses around the denominator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic recursion process.

There are three approaches that one might take:

1. recursive method. (needs end condition)
2. while loop. (needs end condition)
3. for loop. (finishes at the end of the loop)

Using method 3 from the above this works:

```py
def Bounce_Calculator(initial_height:float, bouncyness:float, 
    len_travelled=0):
    ''' takes height and bouncyness and returns then next bounce 
    '''

    next_bounce = initial_height * bouncyness
    len_travelled += initial_height + bouncyness

    return next_bounce, len_travelled

# initial conditions
len_trav = 0
list_of_cycles = [0]
h = 100
b = 0.6

# the loop
for i in range(1, 10):

    h, len_trav = Bounce_Calculator(h, b, len_trav)
    list_of_cycles.append(len_trav)
    percent_moved = (list_of_cycles[i]-list_of_cycles[i-1]) / list_of_cycles[i]

    if percent_moved < 0.01:
        # stopped bouncing
        break

print('bounces', list_of_cycles)
print('total length travelled', len_trav)
```

result:

```
bounces [0, 100.6, 161.2, 197.79999999999998, 219.99999999999997, 233.55999999999997, 241.93599999999998, 247.20159999999998, 250.60096, 252.880576]

total length travelled 252.880576
```